# Want make bar graph created using fusion charts a bit skinnier

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I used fusioncharts to create bar chart, but the bars in the chart is a bit wider, I want to make is a bit skinnier, is there is a possibel way to do that because I am not able to find any setting in fusion chart documentation to do so.

Please help, 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution need to increase the "plotSpacePercent", by default it is 20% if we increase it this will reduce the width of graph.

thanks.